# Can I connect and feed multiple USB-C breakout boards into a single USB-C board (for transmitting data)?

Tags: pcb, wiring, usb-c

A USB-C breakout board (BOB) has VBUS, GND, CC1, CC2, D+, and D- pins. Can I "join" multiple USB-C BOBs together by connecting their individual lines in parallel and feeding them into a single USB-C board?

I ask this question because I am not familiar with how this connector system works. I was thinking of making a dock for my external SSDs so that I can plug a single USB-C cable into my computer, but it's really an excuse to learn how USB-C works.

Comment: You cannot connect data pins from multiple devices together like that.  In addition, if you breakout board only has D+/D-, it is USB2 and not a good choice for SSDs, at least if you want them to be fast.

Comment: @user1850479 If data lines cannot be shared, then how can this be done with USB 2.0 flash drives when fed into a hub? Cheers.

Comment: There are specialized USB ICs used in hubs that enable splitting the bus into multiple ports.

Answer (score 2):

No, splitting of USB is not possible by just combining connectors. Physical USB links are between two devices only, so a hub is required to allow connecting multiple devices into a single host port.